# I try to create a carbon footprint calculator using ruby on rails 7. But I can't save and the user's object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Each person must select 4 options from a form to calculate a value. The form is the following:

```
<%= form_with(model: @carbon_footprint, local: true) do |form| %>
  <% CarbonFootprint::CATEGORIES.each do |category| %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= form.label category %>
      <%= form.select category, CarbonFootprint.emission_values[category].keys %>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= form.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

My carbon footpring model:

```
class CarbonFootprintsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @carbon_footprint = CarbonFootprint.new
  end
  
  def create
    @carbon_footprint = CarbonFootprint.new(carbon_footprint_params)
    @carbon_footprint.user = current_user
    if @carbon_footprint.save
      redirect_to @carbon_footprint, notice: 'Carbon footprint was successfully created.'
    else
      render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

    private
  
    def carbon_footprint_params
      params.require(:carbon_footprint).permit(:plug_in, :get_around, :consume, :stay_warm_or_cool)
    end

end
```

my Carbon footprint model

```
class CarbonFootprint < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user 
    validates :user_id, uniqueness: true

    CATEGORIES = [:plug_in, :get_around, :consume, :stay_warm_or_cool]

    def self.emission_values
        {
            plug_in: { fossil_fuel: 2.5, renewable: 0.5 },
            get_around: { fossil_fuel: 2.5, renewable: 0.5 },
            consume: { a_lot: 2.5, a_little: 0.5 },
            stay_warm_or_cool: { fossil_fuel: 2.5, renewable: 0.5 }
        }
    end


    def total
        total = 0.0
        self.class.emission_values.each do |category, options|
          total += options[self[category]]
        end
        total
      end
end
```

And my table

```
  create_table "carbon_footprints", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.float "plug_in"
    t.float "get_around"
    t.float "consume"
    t.float "stay_warm_or_cool"
    t.bigint "user_id", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_carbon_footprints_on_user_id"
  end
```

When I try do display the results this error occurs:  nil can't be coerced into Float

And when I see how the object is saved to the database I see nil for every option.

Comment: Hey - please share your database migration and the incoming params in your create-method (put a "Rails.logger.debug params" before @carbon_footprint = CarbonFootprint.new(carbon_footprint_params))

Comment: Thanks for replying. I shared my table also I put Rails.logger.debug params but forgive me because I am new to rails and I don't know where the message is displayed for debug. However after the response from Smathy my object is saved fine. But my total method is still not working.

Comment: It's in your loga - have a look at the console or your logs/development.log

Comment: BTW - where is current_user coming from? Is it a variable or some method in your ApplicationController?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `select` call in your view you're setting the options to `CarbonFootprint.emission_values[category].keys` which means the name AND VALUE of each option will be just the key itself, so eg. the **value** submitted in the form for `plug_in` will be either `"fossil_fuel"` or `"renewable"` not the actual numbers. You should drop the `.keys` and send the whole hash of `{ fossil_fuel: 2.5, renewable: 0.5 }` etc.

Comment: Ok thanks that worked for my database. I can see inside the console the object was created successfully for example.  [#<CarbonFootprint:0x000056397e
  id: 35,
  plug_in: 2.5,
  get_around: 2.5,
  consume: 0.5,
  stay_warm_or_cool: 2.5,
  user_id: 3  
However something is wrong with my total method. When I try to display it this comes up to my views: nil can't be coerced into Integer
Extracted source (around line #19)
        total = 0
        self.class.emission_values.each do |category, options|
          total += options[self[category]]
        end
      end
end

Comment: Impossible to work through a problem in the comments. If my answer resolved your question then you should accept it as the answer, then ask a new question for your new issue with the relevant details and code to demonstrate it.